# SQL joining same columns in different ways

Tags: sql-server, join

```
select top 1000 
    f.*, s.TimeZoneCode as TimeZoneOrigin, 
    s2.TimeZoneCode as TimeZoneDestination,
    tz.StandardVariation as VariationOrigin, 
    tz2.StandardVariation as VariationDestination, 
    tzv.Variation as TimeVariation, 
    tzv2.Variation as TimeVariation2
from 
    REZNVWB01.MIT.HVResearchDataSetDraft1 f
inner join 
    REZNVOD01.dbo.Station s on s.StationCode = f.TripOriginLocationCode 
inner join 
    REZNVOD01.dbo.Station s2 on s2.StationCode = f.TripDestinationLocationCode 
inner join 
    REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZone tz on tz.TimeZoneCode = s.TimeZoneCode
inner join 
    REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZone tz2 on tz2.TimeZoneCode = s.TimeZoneCode
inner join 
    REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZoneVariation tzv on tzv.TimeZoneCode = s.TimeZoneCode 
                                        and tzv.EndUTC >= BookingDate
                                        and tzv.StartUTC <= BookingDate
```

I have one table with `StartUTC` and `EndUTC` and `timezonevariation` for each row. I want to look at `BookingTime`, and gain the `timezonevariation` for when `bookingtime` is between `StartUTC` and `EndUTC`.

What do I need to change in this code?

```
 inner join 
     REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZoneVariation tzv on tzv.TimeZoneCode = s.TimeZoneCode 
                                         and tzv.EndUTC >= BookingDate
                                         and tzv.StartUTC <= BookingDate
```

Is this code correct if the TimeZoneVariation code StartUTC and EndUTC are between conditions (IE startUTC might be 5:00 and endUTC might be 10:00, I want the TimeZoneVariation value where BookingDate is between startUTC and endUTC)

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Oooh, thanks @SeanLange ... that will be very beneficial to me in future posts as well as in helping others with their questions. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question - merely by the logic - you can use the BETWEEN statement that could make your intent clearer. BETWEEN is inclusive, which means it includes the values at either end of the range in the comparison:

```
 INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZoneVariation tzv
   ON tzv.TimeZoneCode = s.TimeZoneCode AND
      BookingDate BETWEEN tzv.EndUTC AND tzv.StartUTC
```

However, you're not clarifying whether "BookingDate" is a field within "f" or a variable. If it's a variable, make sure you prepend it with the commercial at (@) and if it's from "f", please declare it as such (E.G. f.BookingDate). This practice will make your code clearer to those reading it.

As to your final query ... it might be beneficial to spell out your table aliases instead of abbreviating them so much (I like to break my lines down and do indentation to help visualize the join relationships):

```
SELECT TOP 1000
  f.*,
  origStation.TimeZoneCode AS TimeZoneOrigin,
  destStation.TimeZoneCode AS TimeZoneDestination,
  origTz.StandardVariation AS VariationOrigin,
  destTz.StandardVariation AS VariationDestination,
  origTzv.Variation AS TimeVariationOrigin,
  destTzv.Variation AS TimeVariationDestination
FROM
  REZNVWB01.MIT.HVResearchDataSetDraft1 AS f
    INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.Station AS origStation
      ON origStation.StationCode=f.TripOriginLocationCode 
    INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.Station AS destStation
      ON destStation.StationCode=f.TripDestinationLocationCode 
    INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZone AS origTz
      ON origTz.TimeZoneCode=origStation.TimeZoneCode
    INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZone AS destTz
      ON destTz.TimeZoneCode=destStation.TimeZoneCode
    INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZoneVariation AS origTzv
      ON origTzv.TimeZoneCode = origStation.TimeZoneCode AND
         f.BookingDate BETWEEN origTzv.EndUTC AND origTzv.StartUTC
    INNER JOIN REZNVOD01.dbo.TimeZoneVariation AS destTzv
      ON destTzv.TimeZoneCode = destStation.TimeZoneCode AND
         f.BookingDate BETWEEN destTzv.EndUTC AND destTzv.StartUTC
```

I don't quite understand your last question. Could you please restate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Got it, I was trying to use between but I think I used it wrong, so this worked. thanks

Comment: While this is a good answer you need to be extremely careful when using BETWEEN, especially when it comes to datetime values. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common